# Cucumber Issue - POST request to create a new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, cucumber

I was wondering if anyone here can please help me with this cucumber dilemma.

I'm trying to create a new object from cucumber and, as explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626001/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-a-post-request-from-cucumber-to-create-a-new-object), I created my post request follwing the same guidelines:

`visit "/users", :post, display_name: "test", email: "test@gmail.com", password: "12345678", password_confirmation: "12345678"` .

Nonetheless, I get this error when I run my test : `wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1) (ArgumentError)`.

Does any of you have an idea on how to perfom this request correctly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post the controller code, it seems like you are passing 3 params to a function that is expecting 1 param

Comment: @ricks , well actually my fucntion is expecting a lot more than 3 params. Hence why I was surprised by this error. Apparently, it has something to do with Capybara itself. I tried another trick and it worked.
Thanks for your help though !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer referenced is 10 years old and the second method parameter to visit was actually removed for a very good reason.

A cucumber or feature spec is a high level test that tests the application through the user story. Users don't use cURL and send post requests straight to your application. They fill out forms and submit them to your application. If you want to test that write steps that actually fill in the form and click the submit button.

If your test just relies on a user being present in the database you should NOT need to do a POST request with `page.driver.post` which is ridiculously hacky. Use a fixture or a factory to setup the test instead.

Comment: Filling out the form was my first idea, but when I tried to "find" and "fill_in" it gives me an error " could not find element". So I tried to bypass this by doing a post request. Which also failled apparently., so I'm back to square one